# Creating a Template in Xcode for OpenGL

Tags: c, xcode, macos, opengl

I have a few upcoming projects for school using OpenGL. I am on a mac and am using Xcode, but I want to use the same settings for each project as a template rather than going in and importing the libraries and changing the search paths each time I have a new project, which if I must I can do, but it sucks.

If I have a project already running with the correct settings etc. Is there an easy way I can just save those settings and label in xcode under like "OpenGL Template" and then just open that each time I want to start?

I guess as just a forewarning, I have hardly scratched the surface of the features of xcode and the projects im doing aren't that complex, so I do not know the IDE in and out.

also the libraries im using are the OpenGL framework, glew, and glfw if that helps at all.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note: I recommend avoiding GLEW.  It claims to be cross-platform but it is broken on platforms other than Windows.  If you want to use OpenGL > 2.1 on OS X, then GLEW is completely worthless, as far as I can tell.  You can just use `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`, or you can use a different loader: https://github.com/eug/awesome-opengl#profile-loaders

Comment: I would, but its required by my course...so im stuck in that respect

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, my condolences.

Comment: I'm constantly puzzled by the questions here where people say "Using X is a course requirement."  I routinely wrote assignments in completely different programming languages than the homework assumed, and hardly anybody ever cared.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Same story here (using different languages and/or frameworks).

Comment: its more of a fact of the teaching hardly touches the surface in my opinion. I will graduate with a solid foundation for programming but the college wont teach me anything practical, I have just accepted that for what it is. If there was a problem with glew i dont even think the professor would know what to do about it. So straying from what they are using and doing, when they compile and grade my program I dont want to run into any unnecessary issues.

Comment: any updates on this?